# Nip it at the source - Let's disable Tags that are pending removal

Tags: feature-request, tags

[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is currently pending removal but new questions pop up every hour from both experienced and inexperienced users that use this tag.

If a Tag has already been marked for removal, why allow it to be added to questions?

---

Options to reduce its use in new posts:

1. Remove it from the suggested tag list
2. Disable it from being selectable in the suggested tag list
3. Change background-color to further warn user of its pending removal

**This reduces the amount of clean up work required to eliminate a tag.**

---

I prefer #2 but here is an example of #3

[image]

Comment: @TinyGiant it is hardly ever done during a burn, only if it keeps returning after being burninated. As such it isn't part of the burnination process: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411

Comment: @rene  - There is no incentive for users to not use the tag during a burn.  Is there another way that you think would help?

Comment: Given that users don't read I'm still pondering if a different color will help. Maybe if it is styled like it is from 90's ..

Comment: It doesn't help that the moderators don't respond when [asked and about the status of the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377772/can-we-get-an-update-on-the-status-of-the-excel-vba-tag). The frequent users of [tag:excel] and [tag:vba] aren't sure what to do about [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: I'd worry that any coloring would actually draw attention to that tag, rather than discourage its use. Could the suggested tag list be sorted so that burning tags always show up last?

Comment: @dwirony It's waiting on Shog to do his final removal.

Comment: @divibisan It'd be a fair amount of work to implement that check against something so dynamic. It would basically need to search meta for questions about a tag that's mentioned in said question somehow (what if they say `[tag]` and not `[tag:tag]` or just "the vba tag") that also is tagged with [meta-tag:burnination] and the [meta-tag:status-planned] tags. Seems like a very expensive lookup each time someone opens the editor.

Comment: @TylerH Better would be if it there was a `DO_NOT_SUGGEST` flag that could be toggled manually on tags when desired which could be filtered or ordered by in whatever query the editor does to populate the list. But this is perhaps getting too complex

Comment: @divibisan Indeed, and it's not likely something that would be exposed to moderators anyway. Shog and other CMs aren't really involved with burninations except in rare cases where large site-wide action is needed (e.g. mass tag removal or blacklist)

Comment: Only CM/admins can blacklist/disable tags.

Comment: I'm missing one big thing here: _Why_ do we need to discourage using that tag? Since it will get removed automatically, I don't really see the harm in keeping it as-is until the tag gets auto-removed, besides the edits from the ones manually removing it, which you should not do imo.

Comment: @ErikA Because it'll never get autoremoved if people keep adding questions to it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That's just not true. The tag that's discussed in the question will get removed as a whole and replaced with a synonym, that can't fail, and we've repeatedly been successful in removing tags that didn't get blocked. Only few questions need to get blacklisted.

Comment: @ErikA Oh, it's going to be synonymised? That makes things easier.