# Tag warning for vba displaying even though there is a host application tagged

Tags: bug, tags

I was trying to see how useful the possible duplicates box on the ask a question page is. But unfortunately I wasn't among the lucky few in the A/B test.<sup>1</sup>

However doing so I noticed the tag warning on the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag:

> You've used the vba tag.
>
> Please make sure to include a tag for the application you're developing on as well:

Seeing this warning supprised me, as the first tag I entered in the tag box was the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not linking the post about this on purpose, as that post isn't featured on purpose.

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/6296561) explains why the warning exists - it ignoring the excel tag seems like a bug though.

Comment: @Zoe, I'm aware of that, would've been beter to include that.

Comment: @Zoe It is a partial bug, but still needs to be implemented.

Comment: @smileycreations15 I highly doubt that. It defeats the purpose of the warning that's designed to detect missing application tags, if it ignores application tags

Answer (score 2):

The system shows the message when there is the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag, and it does not care if it is an application tag.
Also, there is no way the system knowing if it is an application tag.

This would require adding a checking system to check if the tag is an application tag and adding a column for each tag with a warning to check if you added the application tag, the sql product tag, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "sql product tag"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [mysql], [sqlite] etc.

Comment: Problem is, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. The behavior is inconsistent and thus not very logical.