# Edits to a Question

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions

I do know that some questions are written poorly, and do not contain good/enough information.

But I also see (too many!) edits which do nothing to help with the question like, for instance, [Download file from url and save it in a folder using MAC excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62248305/724039)
[image]

A couple of questions:

1. Why was this edit done?
2. What did it add to the question?

In the current situation of this question, the editor did add nothing to the question.

Comment: The tag edit wasn't "nothing" (the argument for vba+excel tags vs the single excel-vba tag is as old as the site and i think the final decision was the 2 separate tags were [the better approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace).  But the rest of the edit is just garbage.  So much more to fix that was ignored.

Comment: Because the editor likes big numbers so made 2 small individual edits which fixed a small fraction of the post instead of 1 big edit which fixed the title, tags and body... I.e. They want their *"posts edited"* number to be as high as possible while doing the least amount of work possible

Comment: Maybe they're trying to start a revolution against [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit).

Comment: Small edits by 2K+ users are super cheap for the site (no review), so ok to make. Excel-vba -> excel, vba and back is good old battle. I don't remember it ever settled... So fighters on each side go and change posts from time to time... Really nothing to look here - edits of 8K+ user are not reviewed and if done slowly will not flood home page. If you feel that this particular change is wrong start separate discussion on "should remove 'how to'" or "excel-vba vs. excel, vba"

Comment: You could ask them. You can @ editors, although it doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: Yes; That question absolutely should have been closed.  Time spent trying to improve it was not worth the time.  Luckily the user who proposed those incomplete edits didn’t take the time of other reviewers to get them approved.

Comment: Ok I Think I know the direction in where to find the answer. The question was meant to be asked in general with only the given post as example. Most reactions are about the given sample.  There are some which luckily take the question, and give some clue about why this happens 'in general'. My personal opinion about this is 'Do not do these kind of edits', which make it usefull this post is closed as being 'opinion-based' 

Answer (score 3):

The first edit is explained in [Merging the [excel-vba] into [vba] - speak now, or forever hold your peace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace)

The second edit was completely superfluous and I have no explanation for it. What the editor should do is downvote and vote to close. The question is suffering from multiple issues and should be closed. The editor was one of the people who voted to close, so I don't really understand their desire to make any edits at all. It makes no difference. Unless the author of this question turns it into a good useful question for the community, the question will be automatically deleted after some time.

The person who made the edit is one of the most avid editors of this site. They make a lot of good edits. Why they are on a personal crusade to retag [excel-vba] question I do not know, but as long as they make their edits count I see no issue.

Because the editor makes useful edits most of the time I would give them a benefit of the doubt when it comes to this one. They made a superfluous edit which was only a waste of their time. The question didn't benefit from it, but it didn't suffer either.

Comment: i do this too, editing(for example show images) and close voting if need be, the number of edits will decrease when the question is deleted, so no gain there.

Comment: "*The editor was one of the people who voted to close, so I don't really understand their desire to make any edits at all.*" I will often make minor edits to correct issues in questions before voting to close them so that it's less likely that any edits are made *after* the question is closed, sending it to the reopen review queue.