# Should [local-functions] be a synonym of [nested-function], or do C# local functions warrant a separate tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

[local-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-functions) is relatively new, being specifically about the feature introduced in C# 7.0, according to its tag wiki (There's no excerpt). It [currently has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-functions) 33 questions, most tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), a few tagged LUA, Python, C++, C, or common-lisp.

This looks to me like C#'s version of the general concept of a [nested-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-function), found in languages like [pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) and a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) in C and C++, allowing access to (some?) local vars in the outer scope.  That tag [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-function) 387 questions in a variety of languages, many of them Python.

---

We often have one tag for the same concept in different languages, like [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list). Instead of hypothetical [fortran-function], [perl-function], [c-function], etc.  But we certainly can and do have tags specific to one language's implementation of a concept, like [stdatomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdatomic) instead of just [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomic). So either choice is potentially valid.

In [discussion in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352468/with-c-sharp-why-are-in-parameters-not-usable-in-local-functions#comment129547721_73352468) on a recent Q&A about C# local functions, [Charlieface](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) suggested the tags should stay separate because C# local functions have their own quirks.

Every language has their own quirks, but a tag search on `[c#][nested-function]` should only find Q&As about C# local functions, or questions with multiple language tags.  So we don't really *need* a [local-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-functions) tag for searchability.

One counter argument is that generic tags like [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) are so broad they become silly for *some* (but not all) of what tags are supposed to be about, e.g. having a gold badge in it from answering [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions doesn't make you qualified to dup-hammer questions about [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) functions, or vice versa (People with gold badges are expected to know when they shouldn't use it, so it's not a big problem in practice. Most questions don't use super-generic tags like [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) at all (fortunately), but [nested-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-functions) is a specific enough and niche-enough concept that it seems fine.).

**I think it would make sense to create a synonym, but I don't have a strong opinion that way.  The tags seem low traffic so it's not urgent.**  But deciding one way or another and fixing up with tag excerpts and wikis accordingly would probably be good.  (The [nested-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-function) tag wiki should mention that C# questions should use the other tag, while every other language should use that tag, if we decide to keep both as non-synonyms.)

We don't need to remove one tag or the other, so taking our time making a decision to synonymize or not isn't letting future work pile up.

Comment: if a] needs an other tag to clarify what it is actually about then that means the tag can't stand on it's own and should not exist.

Comment: @Pizzalord: By that standard, the [assembly] tag shouldn't exist.  IDK if it would be better to have [assembly-x86], [assembly-arm], [assembly-mips] tags...  I don't think so.  Not that one special case justifies other special cases, if it turns out that your point is mostly true in general and tags like [assembly] are an exception.   But there are other tags like [atomic] that also aren't specific enough without a language or context.

Comment: Assembly can exist on itself. You just need to specify on the question body which arch you are targeting. Not every bit of information needs to be on the tags.

Comment: @Braiam: Architecture actually should be in tags, if SO has a tag for it.  The [assembly] tag excerpt says: "*Please tag the processor and/or the instruction set you are using, as well as the assembler, a valid set should be like this: (assembly, x86, gnu)*.  Hmm, I should fix that, [gnu-assembler] is the right tag, not [gnu].  And some questions are more about how the machine works, and don't really need to get tagged [nasm] or [masm].  But there are a few obscure toy / teaching ISAs, and a few real-world ISAs, that don't have tags, so yeah just the question body and/or title is enough.

Comment: The fact that it's a *similar* concept doesn't mean it should be the same tag. Tags are designed so that people can search within them for similar questions, but it's highly unlikely that would happen for local/nested function syntax across entirely different languages

Comment: @Charlieface: You normally need a language tag as part of a search, e.g. [perl][sorting] or [c][sorting].  Expecting people to search on [c#][nested-function] doesn't seem weird to me.  I think one major argument for *not* having a separate tag is that [local-functions] is already getting mis-tagged for other languages, since the tag name isn't [c#-local-functions]

Comment: @PeterCordes for assembly the meaning is the same across all the different version. I am not familiar enough with local functions in c# to determine if the quirks differ enough from nested functions in other languages. If the quirks are implementation details then the combination of the [C#] and [nested-function]  tags should be clear enough to let users know about which specific implementation the question is

Comment: "if SO has a tag for it" so if SO has a tag for apple-pies should I ask questions about apple pie? But that's besides the point. Not because a tag exist it means that a) it's useful, b) is necessary to be included. I'm sure that you've noticed that most often than not you find questions where you don't have to write any assembly to solve the problem at hand, but merely it mentions assembly in the way "why compiler doesn't make the assembly I expect, since I know better than it". Those are questions about the compiler, not assembly after all.

Comment: BTW, considering that x86 (and extensions of x86) is the most common tag used with assembly, I think you will be hard pressed to find a question that isn't about x86 and fails to mention it on the title/body.

Comment: @Braiam: Naive students learning "assembly language" for the first time sometimes don't realize there's more than one flavour of assembly language.  Especially the ones that are so lost they ask bad SO questions :/  Usually people tag an ISA (or at least mention it in the question body), but maybe 2 or 3 questions a week on average require some guesswork or asking in comments to identify an ISA or confirm a guess.

Comment: If there was an apple-pie flavour of assembly language, then yes I'd expect questions tagged [assembly][apple-pie].  Not sure what your argument is here; it should be clear from context I was saying if there's a tag for an ISA to go with [assembly], it should be used for questions involving that assembly language.  Not that the existence of tags can justify questions.  This is getting way off topic from whether [local-functions] should be a synonym.

Comment: Well, people would search on [c#][local-function] because that's what it's called in C#. C# doesn't call it [nested-function]. If we made [local-function] a synonym of [nested-function], that search would automatically be transformed to [c#][nested-function]. That would be fine, but I would worry about people who only deal with C# getting confused as to why the tag keeps getting swapped with [nested-function]. I supposed that's what Meta is for, and dupes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would be very surprised if anyone searched "[c#][local-function]" instead of "c# local function" since the later gives 59 million results vs 0 that the former does. (or 46 if you account for the typo)

Comment: We've had this whole discussion with the *-vba tags already ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893)): tags that require combinations to clarify what is meant should be preferred over tags combining two concepts. So no assembly-x86 tag, no sql-mysql tag, etc.

Comment: @ErikA I think you are combining topics. I'm saying that we only need assembly, and we do not need local-functions nor nested-functions. The language is enough in all cases.

Comment: @Braiam: Most people disagree with your idea that tags other than language aren't useful, so most also won't agree with other arguments based on that position.  Especially for thinks like "local functions" where the two words occur separately in 59 million results vs. 20 questions with [c#] [local-functions], tags are highly useful. (There is no [local-function] tag so of course 0 hits for that.) Of course I'd normally search with google so I could require "local function" to be an exact phrase, which might help some.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please create a synonymn. It is a general programming technique with implementations in many languages with their own quirks just like closures or atomics. The fact that C# calls them "local functions" doesn't mean that "local functions" are actually a different programming concept. It's just like any other programming language's idea of "nested functions" with its own language-specific quirks.