# Will the new question filter ever leave beta?

Tags: discussion, new-nav

I ran across the new question filter/nav a couple months ago when Community bumped [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate). At the time I didn't see that those post were two years old, and so have been waiting for the new filter/nav to propagate out to the other SE sites I am a part of.

Clearly this is not happening.

I know there is a 6-8 week timeframe on this project, but even so, I was wondering if it was abandoned or if we might see it on other sites soon (by soon I mean 6-8 weeks, obviously).

[image]

Should StackExchange be waiting on my opinion before launching it across the other sites, I'll just put here that I am a fan of the "new" filters, make constant use of them on SO, and would like to see them network-wide.

Comment: "Oh this is another one of those new nav things. That entire system is... pretty broken right now. It's fate is not entirely clear. Still being discussed whether someone will be assigned to finish it or if it will just be dropped altogether. You won't see anything further happen with that until our new Product Manager gets up to speed on the project." -- [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295802/direct-linking-to-questions-for-tag-alias-causes-destructive-redirect#comment959726_295802)

Comment: That would be a shame. The new nav system definitely has some problems, and it obviously hasn't been worked on for a while, but I still prefer it over the old "simplistic" system. It just makes it so much easier to find interesting questions in various areas with comparatively complex queries.

Comment: There are still some [pretty big bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav%20bug%20not%20status-completed%20not%20status-declined%20not%20status-norepro%20not%20status-bydesign?sort=votes) that probably need to be addressed, but I agree with @Carpetsmoker, this new buggy, broken nav is still an improvement to the old simple nav.

Comment: Oh no, I really hope they don't drop it. The new nav made finding new questions (as well as keeping track of tags in general) infinitely easier for me. IMO it'd be a much better thing to spend time on than, for example, another iOS/Android app...

Comment: the main developer of that feature isn't working for SO anymore, so I wouldn't be too optimistic about any timeframe here.

Comment: Truth be told I don't remember the last time I've used any other tab aside from "home"

Comment: I use my "C# new" tab every day :)

Comment: I use the tabs everyday

Comment: I use a top voted per week tab because sometimes I learn something, and it at least leaves me with a glimmer of hope that the content quality of the site is advancing.

Comment: It won't be ready to leave beta ***at least*** until custom tabs can update live with new questions. Currently you have to refresh the page or go to a new tab and then click back into your custom tab to see a fresh list of questions.

Comment: I seriously hope it doesn't get abandoned. It is very significantly better than the old system.

Comment: I wonder why this is even opt-in instead of just having a "beta" tab somewhere clearly-visible for all to access. Or they can allow direct access via URL. Or is it a performance-related scaling problem?

Comment: @TylerH I'm confused, my custom tabs update live in the same way that the homepage does (i.e. the gray bar across the top saying "5 new questions" that I can click on to load them)

Comment: @DavidG They do not update if you use rules for a tab. E.g. "this tag and not that one"

Comment: @TylerH You mean like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTpnq.png)?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I have a tab of `css and not javascript and not jquery and not angularjs and not php` and it does not update; never has. As far as I recall SO has not posted a meta update mentioning it being added.

Comment: @DavidG To be clear - the list of Qs does update the live-updating fields that are already visible (e.g. the "asked 25 mins ago" on each question row), but it does not add any new ones or offer a "click here" div to insert new questions every 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: I also have it set to the filter of "needs answers".