# Bug with the menu switcher in tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav

This bug has been bothering me for some time now, but only today I took the extra time to figure out what's wrong with it. I was able to reproduce it in both Firefox and Chrome on macOS.

### Reproduction Steps

I have these customized tabs, but I guess it applies to the default set as well:

[image]

Now, let's say hover over the Forth tab, including its menu switcher (the gray arrow pointing downwards).

[image]

Then, I get over the OCaml tab:

[image]

And click it:

[image]

Notice what happened. Instead of switching to the OCaml tab, it actually opened the menu of the Forth tab. It's quite annoying, because it happens only with the right sequence of events, the one exposed above, so multiple times I got to think that maybe I somehow clicked the wrong area or whatever. Today I've tracked down the issue.

### Issue

If we inspect the element, we notice that it's the right size, 16 × 16 px. So, no problem there.

[image]

However, if we look at the node's text content, we see that it contains the string "expand".

[image]

This is not visible in the UI because it has it's CSS `color` property set to `transparent`, but it's there and it's clickable. And it is actually this text element that's getting outside of the 16 × 16 px area of the button and the thing I'm clicking on when I think I click the OCaml tab.

### Solution

One of:

1. add `overflow: hidden` to `.menu-switcher`
2. remove the text content
3. something else I didn't think about

Personally, I'd go for solution #1.

Comment: Animuson spells it out pretty well in the comment on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349597/will-the-new-question-filter-ever-leave-beta).

Comment: @HansPassant I see. Well, meanwhile I'll fix it for myself through a user stylesheet. I hope the new nav won't be discarded, though.

Comment: This issue also happens on Chrome on Windows 10.