# Can the search results also be automatically refreshed?

Tags: feature-request, search, live-refresh

I'm searching questions with [my relevant tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion), [score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=score%3a3) or [keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22monad%22%20is%3aq)

I want the site to refresh the search result similar as the refresh to comments and answers. (e.g. show 1 more comment / 1 new question)

Can this feature be added?

Comment: That already exists. How are you searching? If you list tags *only* you should get a regular questions list that'll auto-notify you of new posts.

Comment: I'm searching:https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion

Comment: That's not a tag-only-search. You probably want to opt into the ["new" navigation beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate). The project is currently stalled, but otherwise working very well  for me, and it offers favourite tags tracking. Otherwise, you'll have to do a search that includes all your favourite tags manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters aren't you a bit too eager to tag this status-completed? The question is about *search*. That the OP is using tags that has a workaround doesn't mean this feature exists. Searching for `score:3` will never refresh and by that alone this isn't status-completed.

Comment: @rene: the use-case here is to have a page with posts using your favourite tags, and have it be live. We have that feature already.

Comment: @rene: if you want to broaden this to cover all search, then do clarify it and expand on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just did. I think my edit doesn't invalidate your first couple of comments, right?

Comment: @rene: that's quite a broadening, but there you go. It probably is a dupe, I'm sure that has been asked for before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I think it was asked before but my search on MSO didn't give me a dupe target, searching MSE now.

Comment: Best I could find on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142070/add-live-updates-to-stackexchange-com-tag-filters

Comment: @rene: Can't find anything either, surprising. That said, I doubt this'll be implemented. Re-evaluating search criteria on every elasticsearch document update is a very different proposition from a pub-sub network matching against post updates (which is how I imagine the live feature is implemented now).

Comment: Yes, this is super hard, per user, search re-evaluation. Not going to happen.