# Visual bug with new-nav

Tags: bug, new-nav

I noticed a visual bug with the new-nav. I don't know if was intentional or not but I'm adding a gif to show it. Basically padding for the tabs change when mouse enter and leave.

[image]

**OS:** Windows 10
**Browser:** Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: FYI, see [the note on this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate): *"Administrative Note July 6, 2017: development for this project is currently on hold; if you find it useful you may continue to use it and report bugs or suggestions, but fixes / improvements may not be forthcoming."*

Comment: @Stijn thank you for the information.