# Filter and sort bounties after new update?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, new-nav, filtering, sorting

[Remember the "new nav" from 2015?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)

You could filter and sort questions with open bounties by bounty amount, votes, and unanswered.

Now the "new nav" has been taken down and replaced with a new design. We can't filter and sort bounties anymore (we only have a Featured tab). Can the old functionality be restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/296278)**

They're making this now.